# Searching through array of strings to match a keyword string that contains wildcard letters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm, wildcard

I have a keyword string that contains at least 1 wildcard letter; "?".
Each "?" represents a single lowercase letter between a-z.
I need to search through an array of strings to find which letters match the keyword.

```
let input = ["happy", "have", "harvest", "harmonica"]

let keyword = "ha???"

result = "happy"
```

I've tried to replace the wildcard letter ? with regex, but it does not seem to work because it would return "ha/([a-z])+/g" and would not compare like I wanted it to.

I also tried to just replace ? with "", but obviously it would match all of the items so it doesn't work.

Is there any suggestions?

Comment: Not really seeing a coding attempt here?

Answer (score 2):

You could just replace `?` with `[a-z]`, and add start and end of string anchors (`^` and `$`) to your regex. For example:

```js
const input = ["happy", "have", "harvest", "harmonica"]

const keyword = "ha???"

const regex = new RegExp('^' + keyword.replace(/\?/g, '[a-z]') + '$')

const result = input.filter(w => regex.test(w))

console.log(result)
```